# If I can sing to D2 what vocal type do I have?

Tags: voice

When I train my voice I can sing down to the D below the low E on my guitar (I believe this is D2?). When I sing up I start to modify my vowels around Ab below middle C and I have a vocal break on Eb above that. I can then sing head voice and falsetto above to around B. What vocal type do I have?

Comment: We often have questions like this, and I for one can not understand why or how or what difference a label is needed. Please help me understand.

Comment: @Tim: To find similar singers with similar ranges so as to practice for a start. With such a question you might as well question why in classical music people have categorized voice types for hundreds of years no?

Comment: Relevant meta: https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/vocal-type-questions

Answer (score 1):

Your voice type depends on a lot of factors, such as vocal timbre, tessitura etc. However, judging from your range alone, you are most likely a bass (E2-E4).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a classic bass.   Your party piece could be 'Old Man River' in Bb.  You need a good strong low F, and the 'money note' is D above middle C.   A bit of training should keep the vowels pure up to there.

Comment: Sounds like a good one for me Laurence, will check it out. Do basses actually use the notes from say my low D2 up to around F2 in a piece or do they normally sing above this range. For examples, baritones, which happen to be more common than basses, in pop music usually hardly ever go below C3 (the lowest C note on a standard tuning guitar) even though they might train lower.

Comment: Voice type is not about extremes of range.  It's about the sound you make across the core range.

Comment: What do you mean by "core range"?

Comment: The range required of a bass voice is something like F below the bass stave to E above middle C.   Featured solos may go lower, and many basses will be able to go higher, but that's what I'd call the core range.  If you can't cover it, you're not a Bass.    Then we must consider the sound.   Most of the bass range can be sung by a baritone, but with a lighter sound.  (If writing for amateur choir, note than many of your Bass section will actually be baritones, so be wary of writing below A.)

Comment: you were spot on about this and I have to congratulate you because I have been training with this song as per your reply to my post and this song is perfect for my vocal range. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMAZe89O61k  I didn't know it was in Bb minor :) isn't the "money note" an F?

Comment: It is in the version you attached.  But Roderick Williams is a baritone, and ends the song in Db major, 'money note' is F.    Here's Paul Robeson (generally reckoned a bass/baritone, but definitely channeling the Bass persona here I think ) singing it in Bb major. topping out on D.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eh9WayN7R-s Comparing the two is a good demonstration of bass vs. baritone.   I'm sure Robeson could hit a high F, and I'm sure Williams could hit a low one.  But listen to the SOUND.